# Loading HTML5 contents on gallery view seems slow

Tags: android, performance, android-widget

I am developing an online magazine application. It downloads 50 to 100 html5 files from server and store it on sd card and shows this html5 files as pages of magazine. I have used gallery widget to load html pages, It works as my requirement.

But Some issues like loading html on gallery seems slow and  page moves so slowly when swiping the pages still exist. My code is given bellow

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {

    try{
    vi = convertview;
    final int loctn = position;


    if (convertview == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contentsadapter, null);
        WebView webview=(WebView)vi.findViewById(R.id.webView1);


        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.loadUrl(pages.get(loctn));

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                        && view.canGoBack()) {
                    view.goBack();
                    return true;
                }

                return super.shouldOverrideKeyEvent(view, event);
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {

                /*Intent intent = new Intent(Femi9Activity.this,
                        SplashScreen.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Femi9Activity.this.startActivity(intent);*/
            }
        });
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    // Set cache size to 8 mb by default. should be more than enough
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8);

    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);



    webview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gallery.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }

    });
        }catch(Exception e){

          }finally{

                }
    return vi;
            }

          }
```

so the question is

1. How to improve speed of HTML loading.
2. can I load previous and next page html on current page
3. Is there a better way to do this without using gallery

Comment: user `ViewPager` instead of `Gallery`

Comment: hey thanks man. You saved my day. Can you answer my second question?

Comment: yes, but what question?

Comment: I got answer for that question also, but now I am stuck with dynamically adding data's to 'PagerAdapter'. Can you help me?

Comment: you can open a new question !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ViewPager` instead of `Gallery`.